# How do I prove merge works using mathematical induction?

Tags: algorithm, math

Here is the link to my [homework](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n5bhm08uxyoxqvs/a1.pdf?dl=0).

I just want help with the first problem for merge and will do the second part myself. I understand the first part of induction is proving the algorithm is correct for the smallest case(s), which is if X is empty and the other being if Y is empty, but I don't fully understand how to prove the second step of induction: showing merge is correct with input sizes k + 1.

I've done induction before on equations, never on an algorithm.

Thanks!

Comment: Your homework link does not work anymore. Could you please paste the problem here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First assumption: the merge routine you use merges two sorted arrays into a sorted array.
Second assumption: the merge routine terminates

- **Base case:** n = 1, array of 1 element is always sorted
- **Inductive hypotshesis:** merge sort works for n = 1,2,...,k
- **Inductive step:** n = k+1

Now we need to prove the inductive step is correct.

Merge sort splits the array into two subarrays `L = [1,n/2]` and `R = [n/2 + 1, n]`. See that `ceil(n/2)` is smaller than `k` based on the facts above. By our inductive hypothesis both results of merge sort for L and R are correctly sorted (as they are within `[1,k]` range). Furthermore from our assumption merge routine merges them into a sorted array which contains all elements because `size(L) + size(R) = n` so this means that it correctly sorted an array of size `n = k+1`.

@Edit: sorry, missread. For the merge part:

Here we will have a multidimensional induction.

Assumption: input arrays X,Y are already sorted

- **Base case:** size(X) == 0 && size(Y) >= 0 => return Y || size(Y) == 0 && size(X) >= 0 => X, this is true as both X and Y are sorted and merging a sorted array with an empty array yields us the same non-empty array
- **Inductive hypothesis over X:** merge works for merge(n, size(Y)) where n = 1,2,3,...,k && size(Y) >= 0
- **Inductive hypothesis over Y:** merge works for merge(size(X), m) where m = 1,2,3,...,l && size(X) >= 0
- **Inductive step over X:** n = k + 1
- **Inductive step over Y:** m = l + 1

For the first induction step over X we have 2 cases, besides the base case:

- X[1] < Y[1] => `X[1] ⊕ merge(tail(X), Y)` => this is true as `merge(k, size(Y))` is true according to our hypothesis over X and we are putting the smaller element at the front so we are keeping the order
- X[1] >= Y[1] => `Y[1] ⊕ merge(X, tail(Y))` => here we have two options:

  - `size(tail(Y)) = 0` => we hit a base case thus this case is proven to be correct
  - `size(tail(Y)) > 0` => we recurse further finally hitting the base case or `merge(tail(X), subarray(Y))` where `size(tail(X)) = k` => is proven by our inductive hypothesis

Similarly for induction step over Y:

- X[1] >= Y[1] => `Y[1] ⊕ merge(X, tail(Y)) => this is true by our hypothesis`merge(size(X), l)` is true and we are putting the smaller element at the front
- X[1] < Y[1] => `X[1] ⊕ merge(tail(X), Y)` => here we have two options:

  - `size(tail(X)) = 0` => we hit a base case thus this case is proven to be correct
  - `size(tail(X)) > 0` => we recurse further finally hitting the base case or `merge(subarray(X), tail(Y))` where `size(tail(Y)) = l` => is proven by our inductive hypothesis

The algorithm terminates as at each step we are making one of the arrays smaller by 1 element, thus one of them will eventually hit our base case

Comment: I understand your answer for the actual merge sort algorithm, but the merge algorithm on my homework isn't the actual one and works in a different way. Instead of L and R would the answer be they are within the range of [1,k] because the tail of an array is merged with the other array for each iteration?

Comment: @Ugluk sorry, posting before first energy drink isn't good. How about now?

Comment: I really didnt read your answer, but I appreciate your effort for posting such a well formatted answer :D well done ;)