# Bottom up Merge sort proof of correctness and run time

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, merge, correctness

I'm struggling with one question on my assignment regarding bottom up merge sort.
Bottom Up merge sort divides an array into sub-arrays of two and sorts its members, then combines (merges) every two consecutive sub-arrays into another set of 4-sized sub-arrays, and so on until there are two arrays of size n/2, that merge into a completely sorted array.

I completely understand the algorithm but I'm having trouble with proving it formally using induction.
I'm supposed to prove its correctness under the assumption that n is a power of 2.
then I'm asked to calculate and prove its run time which is also by induction.

my current progress consists of proving that at each iteration i the number of sub arrays that are sorted is n/2^i,I'm not getting anywhere with that maybe because I'm looking at it in a wrong way.

Any guidance on how to prove this using induction?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269659/how-do-i-prove-merge-works-using-mathematical-induction

Comment: The run time part is confusing; do you mean operation count or Big O maybe? Big O would make the most sense, as the operation count depends on your implementation, not just the algorithm.

Comment: by run time I mean Big O, which is supposed to be O(nlogn) in this case I believe, as for the link Jim that's normal recursive sort, proving recursive algorithms is different from iterative algorithms.

Comment: The recursive version differs from the iterative version only in the order in which it merges subarrays. I didn't vote to close as a duplicate, but rather provided the link as an example of inductive proof that you could use as a guideline. Much of that proof is relevant to your problem, seeing as how both algorithms do essentially the same thing. My assumption was that you wanted a hint to help you solve the problem.

Comment: thanks Jim, I indeed wanted only a hint, I just thought that in iterative algorithms the proof is done over an iteration i, I will try proving it on n and see how it goes.

Comment: A classic merge sort divides an array of size n into n sub-arrays of size 1, and starts merging sub-arrays until just one sub-array is left, the sorted array. Usually the merging is done left to right on each merge pass. Since a sub-array of size 1 can be considered sorted, then the proof remains in the merge process.